# JSON.NET: Get a sub value?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.ios, google-api, json.net

The Google Reverse Geocode API returns a json response:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

How do I get the lat/long out of it using JSON.NET on Monotouch ?

```
geometry": {
     "location": {
         "lat": 37.4220279,
         "lng": -122.0840677
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the System.Json Classes.

You can find more about it here : [JSON de-serialization with MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003901/json-de-serialization-with-monotouch)

Comment: We investigated System.Json, but it lacks the type conversion in Jason.Net. I like being able to have a properly constructed object handed back and not have to populate it. Less coding.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse the JSON response returned by that URL and put it into a JObject. From there you can get the lat and lng via:

```
jObject.location.lat;
jObject.location.lng;
```

where jObject is the JObject instance.

Comment: DOesn't work in Monotouch as Monotouch doesn't have Dynamic Types.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not see that this question had a MonoTouch tag. This might be of some help though, and it seems to suggest that you can deserialize a JSON instance in MonoTouch with using "JsonConvert": http://brettnagy.com/post/2009/11/21/Using-JsonNET-with-MonoTouch.aspx

Answer (score 1):

iOS has a built in wrapper doing this - [MKReverseGeocoder](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.MapKit.MKReverseGeocoder).